# Infinispan: How to get notified when entry is evicted from backing singleFileStore

Tags: caching, infinispan, evict

The standard eviction event fires when a cache entry is evicted from the in-memory cache. In our case we need a notification only when it is evicted from the restart-persistent disk cache which is configured to be a SingleFileStore. Is that even possible?

We're using Infinispan as a local cache, so any clustering considerations are moot for us.

Our cache configuration is as follows:

```
    manager.defineConfiguration("eviction-test-cache", new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .persistence().addSingleFileStore().location("eviction-test")
                .maxEntries(500).preload(true).purgeOnStartup(false)
            .eviction().strategy(LRU).maxEntries(100L)
            .build());
```

Answer (score 2):

This was cross posted to: https://developer.jboss.org/message/935198#935198

To quote my response from there:

> The maxEntries=500 here is specific to SingleFileStore and removes entries without notifications as this is outside of the normal scope of eviction.  If you want you can create an improvement JIRA to add some sort of notification specifically for SingleFileStore (although I am not quite sure what that would look like).  Another option is you can use the new soft-index file store [1] which can be acquired at [2] (this doesn't have the issue of storing every key in memory.
>
> [1] http://infinispan.org/docs/8.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_soft_index_file_store
>
> [2] http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-persistence-soft-index

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with the stock `SingleFileStore`.